# Get a string from javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object.

```
{
    A: 1,
    B: 2,
    C: 2,
    D: 1,
    E: 1,
    F: 4,
    G: 6,
    H: 2
},
```

I want to grab a four letter string depending on which key has the highest value BUT the string can only be made from the following 16 combinations in the order they appear in the object:

```
A or B
C or D
E or F
G or H
```

So there are 16 possible combinations. The above example would result in the string "BCFG"

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Post your homework as a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

You could

- get the entries of the object,
- pair two entries,
- map the letter of the grater value,
- join the array to a single string.

```js
var object = { A: 1, B: 2, C: 2, D: 1, E: 1, F: 4, G: 6, H: 2 },
    result = Object
        .entries(object)
        .reduce((r, a, i) => {
            if (i % 2) {
               r[r.length - 1].push(a);
            } else {
                r.push([a]);
            }
            return r;
        }, [])
        .map(([a, b]) => a[1] > b[1] ? a[0] : b[0])
        .join('');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I compare each pair in the object then construct the result string from the higher ones.

```js
const obj = { A: 1, B: 2, C: 2, D: 1, E: 1, F: 4, G: 6, H: 2 } //"BCFG"

let getHighest = (obj) => {
  let result = "";
  // Convert the object into an array
  obj = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return [key, obj[key]];
  });
  // Iterate through the array by i + 2 (skipping 1 in each loop)
  for (let i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i += 2){
    // The first one of each pair is more than the other one
    if (obj[i][1] > obj[i+1][1]){
      // Add the letter to the result
      result += obj[i][0];
    }
    // The second is greater or equal
    else {
      // Add the letter to the result
      result += obj[i+1][0];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getHighest(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = {
    A: 1,
    B: 2,
    C: 2,
    D: 1,
    E: 1,
    F: 4,
    G: 6,
    H: 2
};

var result = Object.keys(values).reduce(function(result, value, index, array) {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    result.push(array[values[value] > values[array[index + 1]] ? index : index + 1])
  }
  return result;
}, []).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var vs = { A: 1, B: 2, C: 2, D: 1, E: 1, F: 4, G: 6, H: 2 }
var letters = [];
var numbers = [];
var phrase = "";

for (var key in vs) {
    letters.push(key);
    numbers.push(vs[key]);
}

for (var i = 1; i < letters.length; i += 2) {
    if (numbers[i-1] > numbers[i]) {
        phrase = phrase + letters[i-1];
    } else {
        phrase = phrase + letters[i];
    }
}
```

Probably the simplest version of what you're asking for. Create arrays you can work with as indexes, and then work in sets of 2.

There's more clever answers you can use, but it won't be usable as your homework ;)